# Passing Authorization header in post call

Tags: flutter, dart

I have to pass header data and my code looks like this and after passing this data its giving me failed to parse header issue. What could be the reason ?

```
Map < String, String > userData = {
    "client_id": "value",
    "client_secret": "value",
    "grant_type": "value"
};
Map < String, String > headersMap = {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'authorization': 'Basic <token to be passed>'
};
var jsonBody = json.encode(userData);
final encoding = Encoding.getByName('utf-8');
http.post(uri, body: jsonBody, headers: headersMap).then((http.Response r) {
    print(r);
    if (r.statusCode == 200) {
        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(content: new Text("User Info Updated"), ));
    } else {
        print(r.statusCode);
        print(r.body);
    }
});
```

I have even used dio and passed headers data like this

```
Map < String, String > headers = new Map < String, String > ();
headers['Authorization'] = "Basic <token>";
headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json";

Options options = Options(
    headers: headers,
);
```

or

```
var httpHeaders = {
    'Authorization': "Basic <token>",
    'Content-Type': "application/json"
};

dio.options.headers = httpHeaders / headers;

response = await dio.post('/oauth/token',
    data: jsonBody, options: options, );
```

Also I have tried some Post method calls without any headers(sample post request) and it works fine

I want the header parsing issue to be gone and get proper response

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the the same apostrophe ( mark in caracter ) .  hope it helps

```
 map['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ${user.accessToken}';
```

or

```
var head = {
          "Authorization": "Bearer ${accessToken} ",
          "content-type": "application/json"}
```